# Expected waiting time

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

You arrive at a station at time t=0. Train A can come anytime between [0,5] and train B can come anytime between [0,7] and train C can come anytime between [0,9]. You will board the first train you get. What is your expected waiting time?

Assume uniform distribution for train arrival